# angular "controller as" + "controller constructor" + prototype oop + explicit injection service inside the base class (using [...])

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

1. I am using the angular "controller as" syntax, just provide the 'Constructor' when register a controller.
2. I also want to implement the inheritance with 'prototype' syntax

here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module("test",[]);

        //----------------------------
        function BaseController() {
            this.name = 'Base';
        }

        BaseController.prototype.baseMethod = function () {
            conso.log(this.name);
        }

        app.controller('controllerBase', BaseController)
        //----------------------------
        function ControllerA() {
            BaseController.call(this);
            this.name = 'A';
        }

        ControllerA.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);
        ControllerA.prototype.constructor = ControllerA;

        ControllerA.prototype.a = function()
        {
            console.log('A specific');
        }

        app.controller('controllerA', ControllerA);
        //----------------------------
        function ControllerB() {
            BaseController.call(this, 'B');
            this.name = 'B';
        }

        ControllerB.prototype = Object.create(BaseController.prototype);
        ControllerB.prototype.constructor = ControllerB;

        ControllerB.prototype.b = function(){
            console.log('B specific');
        }

        app.controller('controllerB', ControllerB);
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="controllerA as vm">
        <h1>{{vm.name}}</h1>
        <input type="button" ng-click="a()" value="A: click me" />
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="controllerB as vm">
        <h1>{{vm.name}}</h1>
        <input type="button" ng-click="b()" value="B: click me"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That is working as expected so far, however my questions are:

**if inside the method 'baseMethod' of the BaseController, I want to use another services like $http, $q or servicexyz ,... how I inject them? (and explicit inject using [...], not implicit)**

```js
BaseController.prototype.baseMethod = function () {
            need to use $http, $q, ... here
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set public property of the controller in constructor:

```
function ControllerA($http, $q) {
    BaseController.call(this);
    this.name = 'A';
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$q = $q;
}

app.controller('controllerA', ['$http', '$q', ControllerA]);
```

Then you would access services like this

```
BaseController.prototype.baseMethod = function () {
    this.$http.get('...')
    // this.$q.resolve() etc.
}
```

Comment: yours definitely okay, I've thought about this, however, let's say I have hundreds controllers which are inherited from the base, then we have to copy and paste ... a lot, and every single time we change the signature of the base constructor then we have to change in hundreds places

Comment: So how would you like it to look, theoretically? Not sure what *"then we have to copy and paste"* means, copy-paste what?

Comment: have you to copy this.$http = $http; this.$q = $q; and paste to each single derived controller constructor? each ControllerA ... ControllerX still need those?

Comment: Of course. It's because you inject services into constructors, so if `ControllerA` needs to use `$http` then you need to `this.$http = $http`. I understand your concern, however I can argue that this design (inheritance with BaseController) is very good. I would not recommend it anyway. But if you go this way, don't make BaseController methods depend on http and $q. As many things in Angular - services can be an alternative.

Comment: I do agree, this design is pretty good, however the derived classes had better just take care of their dependencies and the base can take are of its own. Since we use BaseController.call(this) for the 'inheritance' (not is injected by angular) so, I think I am looking forward for a 'property injection' or 'setter injection', like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649447.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. I tried with the $injector, but it doesn't work, I might got it wrong, .... can you help a sample with the $injector inside the base class?

Comment: Ops sorry, I meant this design is *not* good at all. Inheritance like this is rarely a good idea.

Comment: It's not about whether it will not work in some cases. You can make it work. Like I gave you an example of how you can do it. But as a general advice, prefere [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - this will allow you to avoid this complex constructs like you have with BaseController and prototypical chain. I would not try to do it like you are do it, and would better delegate common functionality to shared services.

Comment: thanks for the link, each has its own purpose of use, the point here is how we use it right and when to use, I will not argue which one is better, I am using both, really appreciate your comments

Comment: not exactly what I want to have, but it is definitely an answer